# Rails join to specific element of has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How could I join to a specific element inside a has_many relation? For example, I might only want to join/load the newest datapoint for a device, or the latest pushtoken for a user...

I would like to be able something like the following

```rb
Device.joins(:last_datapoint).where(last_datapoint: { lat: 45 })
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could `JOIN` by [Using a String SQL Fragment](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-a-string-sql-fragment) with `subquery`:

```rb
# Query with condition (lat: 45) and just have latest datapoint for each device
subquery = Datapoints.where(lat: 45)
                     .order(:device_id, created_at: :desc)
                     .select('DISTINCT ON (device_id) *')
                     .to_sql

Device.joins("INNER JOIN (#{subquery}) AS datapoints ON datapoints.device_id")
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough... There is no last_datapoint-relation, only datapoints

Comment: @fynsta I see, you could try the updated answer.